# matplotlib: how to hide grey border around the plot

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to save figurecanvas as bitmap and don't need grey border around the plot in it. How can I hide this?

Comment: @Alex, can you include some sample code that demonstrates your problem?  I'm trying to code up a sample with the wxAgg backend but can not get the call to figurecanvas.tostring_rgb() to work.

Comment: @Mark, if you showed me your code I could try to find the ploblem. Did you call draw() before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: subplots_adjust.

Comment: Can anyone explain how Matplotlib sizes / packs things in general ?
Take for example 3 vertical subplots with titles and xlabels:
how much space do title1 plot1.h xlabel1 hspace title2 ... get ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `savefig` will not include the gray border by default. However, `.bmp` is not support by `savefig`; use `.png` instead.

```
import pylab
f = pylab.figure()
ax = f.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
f.savefig('image.png')
```

Output:

[image: Simple Plot.]
<sub>(source: [stevetjoa.com](http://up.stevetjoa.com/simpleplot.png))</sub>